# Formal definition of Real Numbers

Tags: notation, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I was recently getting started with mathematic formal notation by defining sets of numbers. In Wikipedia, there are some of them definited as:

$\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3\ldots\}$

$\mathbb{Q} = \{ p: \quad p= \frac{a}{b} \quad / \quad a, b \in\mathbb{Z} \quad \land \quad b\neq 0\}$

But I found out, that irrational numbers can't be defined without real numbers, irrational numbers are defined as:

$\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$

So I was trying to define real numbers but there was no definition for irrational numbers that could help me to define real numbers, so how can I define real numbers in this kind of notation?

Comment: There are [several constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Explicit_constructions_of_models), or you can take the [axiomatic approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach).

Comment: The 2 main ways are (1) via Cauchy sequences of rational numbers (2) via Dedekind cuts. (1) is the way most analysis books do it

Comment: The textbook [Analysis I by Terence Tao](https://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Third-Texts-Readings-Mathematics/dp/9380250649) is a very good one. It starts from natural numbers and constructs integers, rationals and finally real numbers.

Comment: A classic reference is Landau's *Foundations of Analysis*: it is beautifully written and a rare example of a presentation of a sequence of formal constructions in precise detail that is thoroughly readable. ...

Comment: Note that although your definitions of $\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ use familiar notations, there are issues (which Landau and the other references in the comments above address) about what those notations mean as part of a formal construction. Is $-0$ a member of $\Bbb{Z}$? How do you add and multiply elements of $\Bbb{Z}$? Does $2/4 = 1/2$? what is $(3/5) + (5/7)$?